# UseNavigate is not working for dynamic search query

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-router

useNaviagte() of `react-router-dom:^6.7.0` is not working for a dynamic search query. How to use my search text as a navigating route?

My Search component:

```js
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';

function SearchBar() {
    const [searchItem, setSearchItem] = useState("")
    const navigate = useNavigate();

    const handleSubmit = (e) =>{
        e.prevnetDefault()
        navigate(`/search?q=${searchItem}`)
    };

  return (
    <div className='search-bar'>
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            <label htmlFor='search'>Search: </label>
            <input
                type= "text"
                id= "search"
                onChange= {(e) => setSearchItem(e.target.value)}
            />
        </form> 
         ... ...
```

In App.js:

```
{
    path: "/search",
    element: <div><Search/></div>,
  },
```

Package.json:

```json
"react": "^18.2.0",
"react-dom": "^18.2.0",
"react-router-dom": "^6.7.0",
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it looks like there is a typo when you call `e.preventDefault()`. That may be causing an issue. Also, you could use controlled input by adding a `value` attribute to your input field like:

```
<input
  type= "text"
  id= "search"
  value={searchItem}
  onChange= {(e) => setSearchItem(e.target.value)} />
```

It would be helpful if you shared your search route page to share the code you are using there. You can use [useSearchParams](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/hooks/use-search-params) to grab the search parameters on your search page.

Comment: Exactly. Typo creates the issue. Thanks a lot.